# React Native Styling Precedence

Tags: react-native

This question is about using an array arg for the styling prop on a react component:
 `style={[styles.localTextStyle, textStyle...]}`

As I understand precedence is from last element to first. So in the example above textStyle would overwrite styles.localTextStyle. This is good, however, I am making a custom component and I want to be able to specify inline props from the parent and have the inline be of highest precedence yet not overwrite previous styles if no prop is provided.

For example, if I were writing a custom component called Text:

```
<Text style={[styles.localTextStyle, textStyle, {
      color: color
}]}>
```

I would use `localTextStyle` as defaults then styling passed from parent called `textStyle`, and finally the prop called `color` to set the color. This only works when the prop `color` is defined, otherwise, it will overwrite `color` to unset despite it possibly being set in `textStyle` for earlier styling.

So I'm wondering what the best way to circumvent this is. I currently have wrapped the final arg in a function called `Clean` which returns a new object with only defined keys-values. That works but it makes the code messy and I'd be shocked if someone didn't have a smarter, better way to do this.

```
<Text style={[styles.localTextStyle, textStyle, Clean({
      color: color
})]}>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's written inside the [Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style) that :

> You can also pass an array of styles - the last style in the array has precedence, so you can use this to inherit styles.

And I checked and It's like that :

[Component-Style] < [inside-array] < [outside-the-array]

like this :

- TSButton has it's own styling in it's declaration

`<TSButton style={[Style.button,{padding:0,width:50,height:20}]} />`

So here the priority is as >>

`TSButton Styling < Style.button < padding , width, ...`

Comment: I knew it was there somewhere. Thank you for finding this I really appreciate it.